# INSERT INTO Syntax error C# access database

Tags: c#, database, ms-access, syntax

When executing this query with parameters added as values, i get an error saying my syntax is wrong. I tried following multiple tutorials, looking up questions here is stack overflow, and when comparing, they seem the same, but mine does not seem to work.

```
OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection();
        con.ConnectionString = "Provider = Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source =C:\\Users\\fidyc\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\ProgrII.accdb";
        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("INSERT Product_Orders(order_ID,plankCount,thickness,width,height)VALUES(@order_ID, @plankCount, @thickness, @width, @height)");
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@order_ID", OleDbType.Integer).Value = orderID;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@plankCount", OleDbType.Decimal).Value = plankCount;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@thickness", OleDbType.Decimal).Value = thickness;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@width", OleDbType.Decimal).Value = width;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@height", OleDbType.Decimal).Value = height;
        cmd.Connection = con;
        con.Open();
        if (con.State == ConnectionState.Open)
        {

            /*try
            {*/
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                MessageBox.Show("Data Added");
                con.Close();
            /*}
            catch (OleDbException ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Source);
                con.Close();
            }*/
        }
```

Edit: values are passed to the function

```
public static void Push(int orderID, decimal plankCount, decimal thickness, decimal width, decimal height)
    {
```

Comment: Access SQL and MS-SQL SQL (T-SQL) are not compatible. You cannot use named-parameters `@`, you can only use positional `?` parameters, and your `INSERT` statement needs to be the full `INSERT INTO` version.

Comment: @MichaelRoy - That is not the problem, tried with and without (different tuts had different syntax)

Comment: That is invalid @Dai access accepts the same syntax as SQL, so the same goes with the named parameters.

Comment: What is the exact exception message?

Comment: @ngeksyo System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: 'Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement.'

Comment: Look at your query you have only `insert` and not `insert into`

Comment: @Fidycent Access's SQL dialect has not been updated since the early 2000s, it lacks many powerful features present in T-SQL. Access itself does not support named-parameters, but the `OleDb` API can shim it in with some caveats. Access does have limited support for named placeholders in queries (where it will pop-open a an input prompt dialog), but this does not extend to OleDb.

Answer (score 0):

The problem turned out to be the count column name, as sql has a count command, it needs to be

```
 OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO Product_Orders(order_ID,[count],thickness,width,height)VALUES(@order_ID, @count, @thickness, @width, @height)");
```

instead of

```
 OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO Product_Orders(order_ID,count,thickness,width,height)VALUES(@order_ID, @count, @thickness, @width, @height)");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
using (OleDbCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
 {
   cmd.CommandText = 
   "INSERT INTO bookRated "+
   "([firstName], [lastName]) "+
   "VALUES(@firstName, @lastName)";

    cmd.Parameters.AddRange(new OleDbParameter[]
       {
        new OleDbParameter("@firstName", firstName),
        new OleDbParameter("@lastName", lastName),
        });

           cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
      }
```